# What is the process to convert gensim KeyedVector to model?

Tags: python, model, gensim, word2vec

I would like to load a gensim pretrained model and continue training it.

This example fails...I've tried many variants and gensim API, but what I'm trying to do doesn't seem possible.

```
import gensim, logging, os
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

import gensim.downloader as api
wv = api.load('word2vec-google-news-300')

# this fails - TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
model = Word2Vec(wv)

class MySentences(object):
    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.dirname = dirname

    def __iter__(self):
        for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname):
            for line in open(os.path.join(self.dirname, fname)):
                yield line.split()

sentences = MySentences('all-tokenized-sentences.txt')

# Training the model with list of sentences (with 4 CPU cores)
model.train(sentences, workers=4)
```

Comment: What is exactly the error you are getting?

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Please have a read on [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and provide full information (e.g. full stack trace, minimal self-contained example of input data that demonstrates the behaviour you see as an error.